# How to filter dataframe by hour?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
|Job    | Time   |
|-------|--------|
|A      |10:00:00|
|B      |10:00:00|
|C      |11:00:00|
|D      |11:30:00|
```

The format of the Time column is a string. I want to filter the dataframe, to create another dataframe that only consist of the job between 10:00:00 and 11:00:00.
How to do the filtering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep it as a string, then simply:

```
df[(df['Time'] >= '10:00:00') & (df['Time'] <= '11:00:00')]
```

or using `.between` per jezrael's suggestion, but `pd.to_timedelta` is not required if you are keeping it as a string.

```
    Job Time
0   A   10:00:00
1   B   10:00:00
2   C   11:00:00
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) with [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[pd.to_timedelta(df['Time']).between('10:00:00','11:00:00')]
print (df)
  Job      Time
0   A  10:00:00
1   B  10:00:00
2   C  11:00:00
```